# Deutsche Bahn: Cancelled connection and timetable change

Tags: trains, deutsche-bahn

I booked ICE/IC trains from Berlin Ostbahnof to Amsterdam Centraal for the 9th of October. I had two connections. My first train was scheduled for the 9th of October at 00:11.

I received an e-mail stating that one of the connections is canceled so I need to check for an alternative. When I checked the trains for alternative routes I figured out that the first ICE train was also re-scheduled to 23:56 on the 8th of October. Therefore, the date has changed to one day earlier. Based on what I read, I'm not able to take that train anymore because my ticket is valid for the 9th of October.

I have two questions:

1- I can take any connection between Berlin Ostbahnof and Amsterdam Centraal with my current ticket because my arrival will be 20 minutes later than my booked trip and my booked trains are ICE/IC trains. Is this true?

2- The next train DB shows me as an alternative from Berlin Ostbahnof departs at 4:30 a.m. My original ICE train is departing from Berlin Hbf at 00:11 am, so it is still the same day as my ticket and it is a later stop than my original stop. Can I take the train from Berlin Hbf instead of Berlin Ostbahnof?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you book the ticket (and what type of ticket do you have)?

Comment: I booked the ticket via https://www.bahn.de/ I don't remember selecting any ticket type while booking. I checked the ticket now and I see Super Sparpreis EU. I guess this is the ticket type

Comment: Without trying to find the written statement and from own experience: Just take the train (if leaving 15 minutes earlier is not an issue for you). There won't be any problem. Your usual rights are not void just because the train leaves at midnight. You can board at Hbf, but seat reservations will be lost.

Comment: Ask customer service of DB. Usually in case of delays they authorize you changes (also with better trains). Possibly the personal on train will have same flexibility, but I find less stressful going to customer services and so you have a written confirmation.

Comment: I sent an email to the customer service. Unfortunately, they haven't replied yet :(

Answer (score 1):

The rules for tickets in Germany are like this:

- Tickets are by default valid for a whole day.
- To get a discount you have to accept a "zugbindung", that is you have to start your trip on the train you selected during booking.
- If that train is cancelled or delayed your ticket becomes flexible by default.

Did you originally book ICE 948? That train appears to be running earlier on your day than originally planned. So you have the option to:

- Still take that train, just board it earlier (at Ostbahnhof).
- Or take any other combination of trains on the Berlin - Amsterdam route on October 9th...

Comment: The complication here may be that ICE 948 does not run earlier on the day, but late on the previous day. 99% sure it won't be a problem to board that train in practice, but when literally reading the rules?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Yes, I originally booked ICE 948. So I can still board it despite its date is changed and then I can take any connection (because of the canceled connection) through Amsterdam after that, right?